# trying to resolve hostname using nslookup - shows ip's in different order each time

Tags: windows, nslookup

lets say i got a computer named - hostname1 i got 2 ips(2nics) for it. - 192.168.5.5 & 192.168.5.6

when i do nslookup hostname1 it resolves 192.168.5.5 192.168.5.6

if i do nslookup hostname1 again it resolves 192.168.5.6 192.168.5.5

if i do same thing again, it resolves 192.168.5.5 192.168.5.6

everytime when i try to resolve -- why order of ip changes??? any ideas? i tried ssome troubleshooting but cannot find what issue it.

i checked dns server, it looks good.

Comment: This is a simple but fairly crude method of distributing load over multiple servers and/or networks called [Round-Robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS). Note programs resolving through the OS (not nslookup) cache the DNS response and use it until TTL expires, so they son't switch _rapidly_, but likely will eventually. In windows you can look at `ipconfig /displaydns`.